# How to receive key presses when out of focus C# Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an app that waits for the user to input a keyboard shortcut and then the program types the corresponding character i've set to that shortcut , the problem is that because this program will be used on word/notepad  ect, the window of my app is out of focus and doesn't recognize any key strokes.

Comment: You either (1) Poll the keyboard with `GetAsyncKeyState()`, (2) Register your hotkey with `RegisterHotKey()`, or (3) Install a low level keyboard hook via `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`.  Search SO for those keywords, or do a Google search; tons of examples out there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetAsyncKeyState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) may be what you are looking for.
Because it's in Winuser.h from the Win32 library (which is mainly for C/C++), you will need to import the file as such:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 vKey);
```

Note that `GetAsyncKeyState()` takes a [virtual key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) as an argument.

If you come across any confusions as to how to use this function in C#, I believe [this](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAsyncKeyState.html) to be a great reference.

> [...] for hotkeys and such. This works even if the window isn't focused.

Here is example C# code using `GetAsyncKeyState()`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 vKey);

int VK_SHIFT = 0x10;
        
while (true)
{
    short keyStatus = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);

    if ((keyStatus & 1) == 1)
    {
        // once control flow reaches this block, the SHIFT key was pressed.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much ill try your advice and i'll reply if it works or not , second i'm new to coding and i haven't seen this syntax `(keyStatus & 1)` what does only one & mean , also what is this called :

`[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 vKey);`

a dll import?
asking for future reference sake

Comment: @Ledrake `&` means a bitwise AND operation.
The `DllImport` part states that you wish to use a certain function specified in the encapsulated API (dll file, in our case `User32.dll`, which interfaces functions for user interaction in the Windows library).
`extern` specifies that the following function exists elsewhere than in your program.
I'm very limited by SO comments, but here are some key words to look more into if interested: "bitwise AND", "dll import" and "extern keyword".
If this solution worked for you, please mark the answer as the solution by ticking the checkmark. Good luck!